# create itune like menu in ios

Tags: ios, ios6

I want to create a menu like in mac itunes app with sliding [image]

I want to create menu like this in my iphone application using ios 6 story board is it possible ? Can anybody find me a good tutorial for that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this tutorial : http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/

I also found this on github : https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try googling something along the lines of "ios coverflow example".

I did a search for you:

https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow

http://code4app.net/ios/Cover-Flow/4f7feab906f6e79f76000000

Comment: than you very much i dont know what the word that i want to search for thank you very much